# Is It Possible to Make a File with a Function in Python?

Tags: python, function, file

I am trying to make a file with a function in python, but I have no idea how. This is what I have, and what I need.

```
def file_maker():
  file_number = input("What number player are you? ")
  #Insert however you make a file in code, naming it ('inventory.' + filenumber + '.txt')
```

I only need to know how I would initiate the file-making process. I tried googling it, but the only thing that comes up is how to access a function within a different file. I am an amateur programmer, any and all suggestions are welcome. Thanks for your time.

Comment: One thing that will help you is to understand that anything you can do in a main program, you can do inside a function in the exact same way.

Comment: I use repl.it, I have only ever made files with its 'make file' button.

Comment: This is covered by [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: I have not accessed that website until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def file_maker():
  file_number = input("What number player are you? ")
  with open("inventory.%s.txt" % file_number, "w") as f:
    # Do whatever you need with the file using the 'f' to refer to the file object
    pass # in case you don't want to do anything with the file, but just create it
```

Read more regarding `open` function here: [Open function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

FYI, this will overwrite the file if it already exists.

Answer (score 1):

To create a file, just open in it write mode.
`file_handle=open ('inventory.' + filenumber + '.txt', "w")`

`file_handle` is now an object that you can use various methods on to add content to the file. Read the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Make sure you close the file when you are done with it using `file_handle.close()`

Note: Although this method works, it is usually considered better practice to use `with`, as shown in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59165686/5103577). It uses less code and automatically closes the file when done.

Comment: This answers my question, but the other answer is more efficient. Sorry.

Comment: @PythonNerd That's ok, it is generally better practice to use the `with` like the other answer does.